# Passport session - I want store user information in session, but only id in browser

Tags: node.js, passport.js

In passport's documentation I can read to serialize and deserialize as that:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

because they say: *"In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a user will only be transmitted during the login request. If authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser."*

BUT I need more information in session e.g. admin flag of user, so i wrote that code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    findUser(user.username).then((result)=>{
        done(null,result)
    })
});
```

and now when i execute *console.info(req.session)* - after that i have what i want:

```
  passport: {
    user: {
      _id: '60658af35cecea3308639385',
      username: 'Test1',
      password: '$2b$10$ScrsMi51eUFi4.Iv49aTC.BD/OIuGgtRN9l4R9OGUj3hZEecI9MIC',
      admin: 0
    }
  }
```

BUT I have a question now:
So if I did that not by id as is in the documentation but by entire user, Does entrie user is id now AND all this informations are in cookies browser of my user? How to carfully store e.g admin flag in session - more information about this user but not in his browser only in session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use express session which can store data and make secret as difficult as can. Here is an example to use it.
[Express-Session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

```
   app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```